# Entity Framework Not Giving the correct name in the database

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity, code-first, poco

I am using entity framework (for learning) to create the datatable; however, when I run the application, it creates the database column name as: AnaKategori_ANA_CATEGORY_ID.

Why is it doing that since I am specifically telling it to name the column as "ANA_CATEGORY_ID"?

Below is the class files content.

```
[Table("CATEGORY")]
public class Kategori
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CATEGORY_TR { get; set; }
    [Column("ANA_CATEGORY_ID")]
    public virtual AnaKategori AnaKategori { get; set; }

}
```

I tried boindiil's answer prior to posting (which was to use ForeignKey Attribute and I got this error:

```
The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'AnaKategori' on type 'BusinessListingMVC.Models.Kategori' is         
not valid. The foreign key name 'ANA_CATEGORY_ID' was not found on the dependent type
BusinessListingMVC.Models.Kategori'. 

The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
the code.
```

Comment: When you use the ForeignKey attribute, you need to have two fields in your class, an int (`ParentCategoryId`) and also the virtual field.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adonetefx/thread/35e7438b-ec1f-4d1f-bca0-539ccfb9abb1), which points out that this seems to be a bug. In this case you have to use the `[ForeignKey]` [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.foreignkeyattribute%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) to give it the desired name:

```
[Table("CATEGORY")]
public class Kategori
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CATEGORY_TR { get; set; }
    [Column("ANA_CATEGORY_ID")]
    public Guid ANA_CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ANA_CATEGORY_ID")]
    public virtual AnaKategori AnaKategori { get; set; }
}
```